# Assigning point attributes values to respective start and end attributes of polyline using QGIS or Modellbilder

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, spatial-join, sqlite

I have created a line layer manually connecting centroids of my sub catchments, then I have created a point layer (**point2**) of this line layer using ‘extract specific vertices’ function from QGIS, where it will give me the start (**vertex_pos = 0**) and end (**vertex_pos = -1**) vertex of this line.

[image]

Then I joined the name of my sub catchment from my centroid to the created **point2** layer to assign a sub catchment to each point. See the picture below

[image]

now I created a line layer (**Path1**) out of this point layer (**point2**) using point to path function (see picture below)

[image]

Then I created 2 attributes in this **Path1** layer “From” and “To”

[image]

**Now I need an expression to do the following :**

If my FID from “**point2**” = “**Path1**” and vertex_pos = 0 set the TG_ID from the “**point2**” layer into “**From**” attribute of the “**Path1**” layer, then
If my FID from “**point2**” = “**Path1**” and vertex_pos = -1 set the TG_ID from the “**point2**” layer into “**To**” attribute of the “**Path1**” layer

How can I achieve this ?

[**Link to the details**](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mkmab350ix9kysx/AACYKWngIeXtiXnCSwO4byCTa?dl=0)

Comment: Can you share some trial data for testing purposes? I can do the task with a Virtual Layer, will it suit you?

Comment: yes, you should able to get the details about this by searching the following question.
"Join sub-catchment centroid using line and import attributes of it using QGIS Model builder"
@Taras let me know you get the details, otherwise I will upload it with this question

Comment: Yes, I can see it, I suppose it is not up-to-data, because afterwards you did some changes. can you please share the current project ?

Comment: @Taras the link is added now

Comment: Now I understand that you do not really need a Virtual Layer for this task. Did you try to deploy the Field Calculator ?

Comment: I do not know to get the right expression in the field calculator

Comment: @Taras What I want to achieve is shown in the question that i have already posted (Hier is the question: Join sub-catchment centroid using line and import attributes of it using QGIS Model builder)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134702/discussion-between-maiyourathaan-and-taras).